# jquery pre sort rows before outputting them?

Tags: jquery, sorting, html-table, multiple-columns, rows

I have a table with a tree hierarchy structure. Certain rows open up more rows when you click on them and this is all done using jquery. However, I want to sort out that rows that will open before outputting them. Is there a simple way to do this. I'm not very good with jquery so . . .

I have something like this

```
$( "##table" ).find( "tr.entry[con=" + condition1 + "]" ).each( function(evt) {

                                  . . . . .

} );
```

where it gets the rows I want to output for the row that was clicked on and then hides or shows them. However, I want to first sort them based on a column value and then output them. Is there a .sort() kind of a function that can do the job for me? If not, how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

The result returned by `jQuery(selector)` is an array. You can use the `.sort` method to sort them.

You can then use jQuery's manipulators (`.detach`, `.append`, `.insertAfter` ...) to remove and reinsert your elements.

example ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jTuPE/1/)) :

```
var $rows = $('#tbl tbody').find('tr').sort(function (a, b) {
    var va = parseInt($(a).find('td').text(), 10);
    var vb = parseInt($(b).find('td').text(), 10);
    return vb - va;
});

$rows.detach();
$('#tbl tbody').append($rows);
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement your suggestion, but it's not working for me. I'm trying to sort on decimal values in the second column.

Comment: You will probably have to use `parseFloat` and `.find('td:nth-child(k)')`